# jQuery Mobile: Modify DOM when fully loaded to make page 100% in height

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, height

I want to make the content area in a jQuery Mobile page stretch so the page is filling 100% of the viewport (header+content+footer=100%). I would assume that I have to do the height alignments when the DOM is fully loaded so I have the heights of all divs and then I can do something similar like [this](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/jquery-mobile-full-height-content).

jQuery Mobile claims to use [pageInit and not $(document).ready](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html). Unforunatelaty the DOM seems not to be fully loaded when pageInit is called as

```
var header = $("div[data-role='header']")
console.log(header.height());
```

tells me the height is 0. When I use the same code in $(document).ready() it tells me it is 79px.

So what is the best practice to make the alignments?

Edit:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ATfk/) is a jsFiddle that shows the basic structure of my page. I want the canvas to fill the entire space between the header and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that header = [] in your case. But either I don't understand the problem, or I don't understand why javascript is needed. Can't you do it with simple css?

```
.header{height:20%}
.content{height:60%}
.footer{height:20%}
```

or something similar

Comment: of course some simple css would be ok but when I use inline css with % for my header, footer and content div the height doesnt apply and the content height doesnt change. only when I use absolute px values the heights change.

Answer (score 0):

If you're waiting for images (or other external assets) to load then you need to either bind a `load` event handler directly to the elements/assets or wait for the `window.load` event so that the assets' dimensions will be correct.

Alternatively you can give the assets specified dimensions, for instance if it's an image and you know it will be `300px` by `200px`, set those values as attributes or through CSS. This way a correct dimension can be had before the `window.load` event fires and this works with jQuery Mobile page events better since you can't wait for `window.load` to fire when a page is brought into the DOM via AJAX.

If you are using an older version than 1.1.0 RC1 then I suggest you check-it-out, it's got CSS fixed footers that look/feel good and make your page appear 100% height all the time. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/#download

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. as you already mentioned the window.load event won't work for me as I want to use the AJAX link behaviour. as I dont know the dimensions I cant use your second suggestion either. when using 1.1.0 RC1. I added a jsFiddle to my question, maybe this helps sloving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to fill the space between the header and footer, have you considered getting the height of `data-role="content"`?

Answer (score 0):

First,create "pageshow" event for your page:
(it has to be "pageshow" event and not "pagebeforeshow",because in the second case you won't get the height - page is hidden)

```
// bind "pageshow" event to your page
$("#PageID").live("pageshow", function (event, data) {
    // do something...       
});
```

Inside this event,check your header,footer and page sizes (with paddings & margins):
Something like:

```
var header_height = $("div[data-role=header]").height();
var footer_height = $("div[data-role=footer]").height();
var page_height = $("div[data-role=page]").height();
```

Then, calculate and set the new size of canvas:

```
$("#MyCanvas").css({"height":page_height - (header_height + footer_height )});
```

The whole example code:

```
    // bind "pageshow" event to your page
    $("#PageID").live("pageshow", function (event, data) {
       var header_height = $("div[data-role=header]").height();
       var footer_height = $("div[data-role=footer]").height();
       var page_height = $("div[data-role=page]").height();

       $("#MyCanvas").css({"height":page_height - (header_height + footer_height )});       
    });
```